# How to bind web data with fixed and recycling items

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, adapter, android-viewholder

So I have an arraylist of object coming via requests with json..! I got the data using the model class.

I want the data to bind with this layout (see the pic), now the first 3 objects from the model class must bind with 1,2 and 3 respectively and the rest *meaning the fourth object and beyond* should bind with 4 and keeps recycling till it ends..!

basically I want 1,2  and 3 to be fixed and the 4 to be recycled..!

[image]

> I thought of doing 2 requests, one for the fixed widgets and the second
>   for 4 with a recyclerview starting with index 3, but hitting two
>   identical requests isn't a good practice I guess..

Comment: You could do this with one request for a base model and then processing on that model to dynamically create the views for 1 - 3 then processing to create the RecyclerView for 4

Comment: @DavidRawson I didn't fully get what you meant, could you elaborate more please ?